# Serialize and unserialize form elements in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to serialize and unserialize the form elements in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
Description: Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.
```

Answer (score 2):

First stop would be the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)... specifically [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)